# I am unable to solve the maven build errors

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I am getting the below mentioned error while I am upgrading from jdk8 to jdk17.

**Output from the terminal:**

```shell
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 5.938 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-29T09:35:50+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 31M/120M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test)   on project test1: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test failed
```

**This is the output after the changes in the pom.xml:**

```shell
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 18.344 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-08-29T09:45:45+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 30M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M3:test (default-test) on project test1: There are test failures.
```

I have tried changing the version of maven-surefire-plugins i.e, version changed from 2.19.1 to 3.0.0-M3

Comment: Please suggest anything needs to be changed in the pom.xml or in the configuration files

Comment: can you also provide the `pom` file ? just update the question

Comment: Seems like your tests are failing. Maybe disable the tests first and try to run again?

Comment: Normally there's some output above the `BUILD FAILURE` message that indicates why the build failed. As long as that isn't included, we cannot answer the question. Also, if the build fails due to a failing test, then we also need the relevant code for that test (the source and test code). For now I'm voting to close this question as it's missing debugging details.

Comment: First I would suggest to upgrade to most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin (3.1.2) https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/index.html